# Locked Out of Azure VM Instance after Configuring Ubutun ufw

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssh, ufw

I deployed an Azure VM instance running on Ubuntu 20.04.

I never change any networking settings of the VM. It is as such, [image]

However, on the VM instance, I did change some of the `ufw` rules while trying to serve Flask applications with uWSGI and Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed this guide - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04

I realised that the `ufw` was not enabled by default. After enabling the firewall on my instance - `sudo ufw enable`, I was unable to logon to my VM instance via SSH.

The error trying to SSH into the instance was - *Network error: Connection timed out*.

Is  there anyone that can offer any advice to getting into the VM instance again without destroying what I have?

Answer (score 1):

If the firewall is preventing your connection through SSH and you don´t want to modify this rule, I´d suggest using [Azure Bastion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/bastion-overview). You can connect to your VM directly on the browser without exposing any SSH or RDP Ports.